# Xubuntu 16.04 fresh install can't access wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless, xubuntu

Just did a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 on my pavillion x360, booted it up and couldn't connect to my wifi network. I've been troubleshooting for a while, but I can't seem to get it to work. This laptop has no ethernet input so I can't connect that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I did some research and found something about a b43 cutter and installer file, which I downloaded on a separate pc and transferred over. I executed those two on my laptop and got an error because I wasn't connected to the internet so it couldn't access an online broadcom file.

Then I went on to the Xubuntu website and where it said to run the sudo lshw -C network command. And the first line of it said DISABLED

Both Wifi and Networking are enabled

The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)

   DeviceName: Intel WLAN Intel 3165NGWG Stone Peak 1 ac 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe +USB NGFF 2230 WW
   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Duel Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
```

Output of rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
[    7.913596] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-               19.ucode failed with error -2

[    7.913633] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.913656] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.024900] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.424673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    8.424824] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.425099] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.533767] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.664343] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   27.022834] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   27.023114] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   27.084895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   27.085178] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  993.808825] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  993.809126] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  993.875100] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  993.875499] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Comment: Please list the trouble shooting steps taken to avoid duplication from suggested solutions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: And your adapter is not Broadcom.

Answer (score 3):

Your wireless adapter seems to be blocked by `acer-wmi`. Disable it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

Reboot to apply.

Comment: This is perfect, I now have access to wifi networks! Any idea on why the wireless adapter was blocked?

Comment: A wrong platform driver was loaded. Now it is fixed. Do not forget to accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left to show others that it works.