# No wifi Xubuntu 16.04 rufus usb boot

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, live-usb

Fresh install on 16GB USB stick on Lenovo 110S
Can't get connected to a wifi network or any sign that any wifi is being detected.

[Xubuntu 16.04 fresh install can't access wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877002/xubuntu-16-04-fresh-install-cant-access-wifi)
suggests:
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist  acer_wmi"
but requires reboot.
Given this is a rufus stick without persistent storage and presumably a reboot will default to the image settings is there anything to solve or am I best trying another distro ?

Comment: install without wifi, then make the correction, and update after enabling the online repositories.

Comment: The reason is probably that there is no stardard linux driver for your wifi chip. But after the installation, you can install a driver as adviced by @ravery. Is is possible for you to connect via wired internet, 'ethernet', until you have installed the necessary wifi driver?

Comment: @sudodus -- of course a wired connection would be better, but he should be able to install with no internet , yes? Just a few step in the package manager to enable repositories after the situation is resolved.

Comment: @ravery, you are welcome to make an answer with the details how to do it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately no ehternet, just public wifi. Not sure I understand "install without wifi" is there a standard iso image or rufus setting to do this ? Also how do I "enable online repostories".

Comment: May I just be better off searching for a distro that supports my wifi chip ? I just want a small footprint linux for this lil wimpy laptop;

Comment: You can try with Xubuntu 17.10 (which is the newest released version), and  yes, you can try  other linux distros too. How old is your Lenovo 110S (approximately when was is manufactured)?

Comment: I can give directions, but first you need to find a fix that you know works for your wifi card.

Comment: @ravery Thanks. Drivers any use ? https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQws_L7YzYAhWlDcAKHf_bAy4QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fajaybhatia%2FQualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux&usg=AOvVaw1tBf76UcSLvK9iKsYeTw2z

Comment: Well the struggle continues......Installed 17.10 instead and seemingly hopefully a popup immediately on boot says "connections available, check network menu" Yay. FF doesn't connect. Go to network via system: No connections shown in window. Help says run `'network -admin'`. Run in xterm : "No command network". Back to square one!

Comment: yes, that driver might help. You need to boot with secure boot off in order to install a third party driver. Kernel headers and kbuild need to be installed.